# ASP.NET MVC View: The name 'inject' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add Localization to my ASP.NET MVC application. However, I'm already failing at including the necessary packages. I'm fairly certain that my application is using Views, and I'm about 50% sure that it's using Razor pages. At least the Razor pages syntax works, except in this case.

I'm following [this official Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#view-localization) and [this one](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/). Both appear to use about the same code that I'm using. I might be missing a crucial package, though.

Here's part of my `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using System.Threading.Tasks

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The first two `@using` lines work flawlessly. The fourth line throws an error and the page shows an error in the browser.

```
CS0103: The name 'inject' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: `@inject` is an MVC 6 feature and its part of ASP.NET Core. Do you use ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Very good question. How do I check? I have controllers and models and they all work flawlessly, so I thought I was.

Comment: I already set my "Target Framework" to 4.6.1, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I am neither able to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nor Microsoft.AspNetCore.App with .NET version 4.6.1.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I have to go to the VS Installer and add the .NET Core module.

Comment: also if you have resx files, manage your translations with Microsoft MAT ;-) https://multilingualapptoolkit.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out I was missing the .NET Core development environment. You can install it via the Visual Studio installer.

- Run the Visual Studio installer
- Click "Change" to change your existing Visual Studio installation
- Add the .NET Core Extension
- Click "Change" to apply your changes
- Your extension should download automatically.

---

Note that this will not necessarily turn your existing ASP.NET application into a Core application.

[Regular old AST.NET MVC localization appears to be quite easy.](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/53/create-multi-language-website-in-aspnet-mvc---localization) ([Archive link just in case](http://archive.is/HbM6i))

- Add a .resx file
- Reference that file and its resources in your view like this:

`@Resources.<Name of your file>.<Name of the resource line>`

Example:

```
<h3>@Resources.Global.AppName</h3>
```